# GLKIT and GLM Nate Robins

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

First of all I want to thank you for looking at my problem.
Now to Describe.

My problem is that whenever I use [nate robins GLM library](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/) I am unable to load my textures. However, seeing as I was unable to load textures I chose to next create arrays with no texture. None the less, I am still getting  this error. I have ran GlgetError to learn that I am receiving 1282 after glgenTexture() within the EdenSurfaces class of GLM.

```
EdenSurfacesTextureLoad(): GL error while generating texture name.
EdenSurfacesTextureLoad() couldn't read texture file "/var/mobile/Applications/4CD4F74F-AEF0-4D28-93D3-F5DE31938720/ObjLoaderv2.app/model/Data/101.jpg".
glmReadMTL(): Error loading texture.
```

Here is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController{

    GLMmodel *glmModel;
    NSArray *paths[2];
    NSString *myArrayString;

 }

//@synthesize glContext = _glContext;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.glContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.glContext) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.glContext;
    view.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;



}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    paths[0] = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".obj" inDirectory:@"model"];
    myArrayString = [paths[0] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

    const char *stringAsChar = [myArrayString cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

    GLfloat dimensions[3];
    glmModel =  glmReadOBJ(stringAsChar,0);

    glmCreateArrays(glmModel, GLM_NONE);


    glmDimensions(glmModel, dimensions);
    glmDrawArrays(glmModel, 0);

}

- (void) ReadInOBJ:(NSString *)file{
 glmModel =  glmReadOBJ([file UTF8String] ,0);


    if (!glmModel) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Unable to load model %@.\n", file);
    }
}
@end
```

Update: I solved my error my added glGenerateMipMapOES within the GLM library. However, I am still getting any of my model to load within in glkit. Nothing comes and I see now error message. What could I be doing wrong in integrating glkit and Nate Robins GLM?

Comment: Anyone out there with a suggestion on what to do?